# How do I remove a dictionary from a list depending on a value being present in a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I'm new to Python, so apologies in advance if my code isn't written in the most 'pythonic' way.

I am uploading a CSV file to the script, and I want to filter that CSV if the row matches certain criteria.

I have two lists, `a_lst` & `b_lst`. Once the dictionaries are in `a_lst`, I am checking if there is a dictionary with a corresponding key:value in `b_lst`. If there is a a matching item, this is printed to the console. Instead of printing to the console, I want to delete that item from `a_lst`. How do I do this?

```
a_lst = []
b_lsts = []

with open(file_name, 'rt') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
            if row['Minutes'] == '0' and row['MB'] == '0' and row['Calls'] == '1':
                a_lst.append(row)
            elif row['Minutes'] == '0' and row['MB'] == '' and row['Calls'] == '1':
                a_lst.append(row)
            elif row['Minutes'] == '' and row['MB'] == '0' and row['Calls'] == '1':
                a_lst.append(row)
            elif row['Minutes'] == '' and row['MB'] == '' and row['Calls'] == '1':
                a_lst.append(row)
            else:
                b_lst.append(row)

i = 0
while i < len(a_lst):
    if not any(d['Name'] == a_lst[i]['Name'] for d in b_lst):
        print a_lst[i]['Name']+"(Row"+str(i)+") is not b_lst."
    else:
        print a_lst[i]['Name']+"(Row"+str(i)+") is present."
            i+=1
```

**EDIT**: The results I would like

```
Name, PhoneNo, Minutes, MB, Calls
Steve,0777777777,0,0,1
Steve,0777777777,0,2,14
Steve,0777777777,0,0,1
John,078888888,0,0,1
John,078888888,0,0,1
John,078888888,0,0,1
Dave,07999999,2,3,4
Dave,07999999,2,6,24
```

If the above data was my insert, I would only like to see `John`'s name because he is the only person where all of the rows for his name contain the values '0,0,1'

Comment: Show us a sample of your input and how you want to look the output after processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the element from the list if it has  the same key/value, you also want to remove `not` before`any` as we want to remove if there is any match:

```
for ele in a_lst[:]:
    if  any(d['Name'] == ele['Name'] for d in b_lst):
        a_lst.remove(ele)
```

Or just forget about using `any` and  filter before you add, adding `row['Name']` to a set and checking if we have already seen it:

```
seen = set()
with open(file_name, 'rt') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
           if row['Name'] in seen:
               continue
           if all((row['Minutes'] == '0', (row['MB'] == '0' or not row['MB']), row['Calls'] == '1')):
               a_lst.append(row)
           elif all((not row['Minutes'], (row['MB'] or not row['MB']), row['Calls'] == '1')):
                a_lst.append(row)
           else:
               seen.add(row['Name']) 
         # remove "else:" and just use seen.add(row['Name']) outside the elif if you want all dups removed
```

Based on your edit:

```
seen = set()
with open(infile, 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",")
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] in seen:
            continue
        if all(x in {"0", "1"} for x in row[2:]):
            print(row)
        seen.add(row[0])
```

Output:

```
['Steve', '0777777777', '0', '0', '1']
['John', '078888888', '0', '0', '1']
```

Both `Steve` and `John` have only 0 and 1 in their relative columns.

If you  only want names that exclusively have 0 and 1 in their columns:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)

with open(infile, 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",")
    for row in reader:
        d[row[0]].append([row, set(row[2:])])

print([v[0][0] for k, v in d.items() if all(sub[1] == {"0","1"} for sub in v)])

[['John', '078888888', '0', '0', '1']]
```

Or using sets if your names are always grouped together:

```
seen = set()
temp = set()

with open(infile, 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",")
    next(reader)
    prev = None
    for row in reader:
        # found new name and it is not the first
        if row[0] not in seen and temp:
            # set should only hav  and 1 if all columns only contain 0,1
            if temp == {"0", "1"}:
                print(prev)  # print previous row
            # reset temp
            temp = set()
        seen.add(row[0])
        temp.update(row[2:])
        # need to keep track of previous row 
        prev = row
```

Output:

```
['John', '078888888', '0', '0', '1']
```

Comment: I suspect that your second approach may miss the cases when you've already added the value to a_lst, and you get already 'Name' element in second condition

Comment: @volcano, that is exactly what the OP's code is doing. If they want to catch more all they have to do is add to the set after appending each time. As I already said doing the work after is futile, no point adding something to later take it away

Comment: imagine you encounter a row with name 'Padraic Cunnigham' that matches add condition - and after it you find a record with the same name that matches remove condition. It will stay n _a_lst_

Comment: And the first solution is still a problem

Comment: @volcano,  there is no problem in the code, it depends on what the OP wants to do.

Comment: OK, my mistake. I remove the objection

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it's not producing the desired results, Some of the data with values that are not 0 are appearing in a_lst. I've added some sample data and the output I would like, if you could take a look.

Comment: Padraic, one further question. Is there a method of allowing for the possibility of null data where a 0 could be? For example:

Steve, 777777, ,0,1 as well as Steve, 777777,0,0,1

Comment: in any index 2,3 or 4 ? maybe  `if temp == {"0", "1"} or temp == {"0","1"," "}:`